# Why do we need the operator to be densely defined for defining adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Suppose $T$ is an operator with domain and range in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. The usual way of defining the adjoint $T^*$ of $T$ uses density of $dom(T)$. But cannot we use this same definition for general situation where the operator is not densely defined in the following way?

> $dom(T^*):=\{ y\in \mathcal{H}:\text{the map }dom(T)\to \mathbb{C}:x\mapsto \langle Tx, y\rangle \text{ is continuous}\}$

Then by Riesz Representation theorem for the Hilbert space $\overline{dom(T)}$ there exists a unique $z\in \overline{dom(T)}$ for any $y\in dom(T^*)$. We'll define $T^*y=z$ for each such $y, z$.

This definition can be applied to any operators not necessarily the densely defined one and coincide with the usual notion for densely defined case. Isn't the case? If so, then why do we consider dense domain for defining adjoints?

**EDIT:**
If we define $dom(T^*)$ as above then for any $y\in dom(T^*)$ there is a unique $z\in \overline{dom(T)}$ such that $\langle Tx, y\rangle = \langle x, z\rangle$ for all $x\in dom(T)$. There could be many such $z$ in $\mathscr{H}$ but exactly one such $z$ lies in $\overline{dom(T)}$, we'll define $T^*y$ to be that $z\in \overline{dom(T^*)}$. Is there any issue with this definition? Thank you.

Comment: A unique $z$ with which property? $\langle x, z\rangle = \langle Tx , y\rangle$ for all $x \in \operatorname{dom} (T)$? The problem is, that $z$ is not unique in $\mathcal{H}$, because now there are multiple ways to extend $x \mapsto \langle Tx, y\rangle$ to $\mathcal{H}$. So in that case there would be multiple possible adjoints. See the answer by s.harp [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710783/why-need-densily-definedness-for-definition-of-t-for-unbounded-operator).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why need densily definedness for definition of $T^*$ for unbounded operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710783/why-need-densily-definedness-for-definition-of-t-for-unbounded-operator)

Comment: @jd27 Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question. The point is I want to consider only those $z$ that lie in $\overline{dom(T)}$ outside $\overline{dom(T)}$ there could be many such $z$ but inside $\overline{dom(T)}$ there is exactly one. Isn't it?

Comment: @sigma Yes, but it is questionable how useful this definition is. More generally you could define the adjoint for a densely defined operator $T: \operatorname{dom}(T) \subset \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_2 $ between two different Hilbert spaces. This adjoint would agree with your definition in the special case with $ \mathcal{H}_1= \overline{\operatorname{dom}(T) }$ and $  \mathcal{H}_2 = \mathcal{H}$.

Comment: @jd27 For an operator $T$ densely defined with dom and ran in $\mathcal{H}$, isn't this new definition exactly same as the usual one?

Comment: @sigma yes, of course.